# cant print the video title using pytube in python

Tags: python, pytube

i have been having issues using fetching the video title from pytube. it seems that either pytube is having issues fetching the video title or pytube can't seem to get it. i have updated pytube to version 15.0.0 while using a patch.

so i have been having issues using pytube to get the video title of the video using the url link, any leads to fix this issue.

```py
from pytube import YouTube

print("input url below:")
input_url = input()
my_video = YouTube(input_url)
if input_url == "": 
    pass
else: 
    print(my_video.title)
    print(my_video.thumbnail_url)

my_video = my_video.streams.get_lowest_resolution
print(my_video)
```

and here is the error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(censored)\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 330, in title
    self._title = self.vid_info['videoDetails']['title']
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'videoDetails'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\(censored)\Desktop\youtube video downloader\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(my_video.title)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\(censored)\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 335, in title
    raise exceptions.PytubeError(
pytube.exceptions.PytubeError: Exception while accessing title of https://youtube.com/watch?v=vEQ8CXFWLZU. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/pytube/pytube
```

Comment: Did you check the github to see if this issue is already reported?  If not, file a report.  Chances are that YouTube has changed something in the structure of the data that Pytube is pulling, which has led to the KeyError when you ask for the title with `my_video.title` as `self.vid_info['videoDetails']` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a recurring issue with pytube. Since you're already using version 15.0.0 which is supposed to have fixed the issue, you can try [this solution](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1589#issuecomment-1545248602) which is also recommended by [a different solution](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1604#issuecomment-1540908957) on the same bug. You could also consider using a different library to help you get this information or directly call the YouTube API itself. [This is the doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) for the API that gets information about a video.